# Serialize a tree using DFS

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

According to [this post on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), given a tree with distinct elements, either pre-order or post-order paired with in-order is sufficient to describe the tree uniquely. However, pre-order with post-order leaves some ambiguity in the tree structure.

I am looking for a quick example that would demonstrate this claim.

So given the following tree:

[image]

The orderings are:

```
Pre Order:  1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6
In Order:   4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6
Post Order: 4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 1
```

How can I deserialize this tree using its *Pre Order* and *In Order* or *Post Order* and *In Order*?

Thanks

Comment: The tree made is not a binary search tree but a binary tree.

Comment: @NikunjBanka: OK, thanks, I updated the title accordingly.

Comment: @barakmanos Check the source that Wikipedia's article cites, it is explained there: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/439/which-combinations-of-pre-post-and-in-order-sequentialisation-are-unique

Answer (score 0):

So the claim is that given a pre-order and in-order traversal of the tree we can uniquely construct the tree.

In your example 
Preorder : 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6 
In Order : 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6

Now the root node in the tree will be the first node in the pre-order traversal. Moreover, all the numbers appearing before a value in the inorder traversal will lie in the left subtree rooted at that node. And similarly all values appearing after a value will lie in the right sub-tree. So continuing in this recursive fashion will deserialize the tree. You can read more about it here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/

Similarly, you can deserialize the tree given its postorder and inorder traversal. Here the last value appearing in the post order traversal will be the root of the tree. You can read about the deserialization from post-order and in-order from here http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/construct-binary-tree-from-inorder-and-postorder-traversal/

Comment: So the root of the tree is 1, on the left side of the tree are 4 and 2, and on the right side of the tree are 7, 5, 8, 3 and 6. What's next?

Comment: Recursively for the left half inorder = {4, 2} and preorder = {2, 4}. The returned tree is made the left child of the tree rooted at 1. And right half inorder = {7, 5, 8, 3, 6} and preorder = {3, 5, 7, 8, 6}.

Comment: OK, so I find the root of the tree using **PreOrder**, then I find the left and right sides of the tree using **InOrder**. Then, I take the left side, and I find which value is the first to appear in the **PreOrder**. That value is the root of the left sub-tree. Now, I go back to the **InOrder** and I find the left and right sides of that sub-tree. In this example, the left side contains only the value 4. But it's not so easy to determine what the right side contains. In this example it is empty, but how do you efficiently determine that?